# What am I missing about make-symbol and assq here?

Tags: elisp

I am trying to produce the same structure a `let` block accepts for local variable definitions but am hitting a wall: given this `parse` function:

```
(defun parse (string)
  (mapcar (lambda (line)
            (let* ((k_v (split-string line "="))
                   (key (make-symbol (first k_v)))
                   (val (second k_v)))
              (list key val)))
          (split-string string "\n" t)))
```

I get what *looks* like the sought output in lisp-interaction-mode:

```
(setq alist (parse "foo=bar\nbaz=quux\n"))
((foo "bar") (baz "quux"))
```

Given that…

```
(assq 'foo '((foo "bar") (baz "quux")))
(foo "bar")
```

…I would expect the same result below – what am I missing?

```
(assq 'foo alist)
nil
```

While I'd be surprised if Emacs versions mattered, I've been testing this in Emacs 24.2 (9.0) on OSX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `make-symbol` documentation:

> ```
> (make-symbol NAME)
>
> Return a newly allocated uninterned symbol whose name is NAME.
> Its value and function definition are void, and its property list is nil.
> ```

Your `assq` is comparing the *interned* symbol `foo` with some random *uninterned* symbol which happens to be named `foo`, which (of course) will fail, as they are not the same symbol.

Using `intern` instead of `make-symbol` (as below) may solve your problem.

> ```
> (intern STRING &optional OBARRAY)
>
> Return the canonical symbol whose name is STRING.
> If there is none, one is created by this function and returned.
> A second optional argument specifies the obarray to use;
> it defaults to the value of `obarray'.
> ```

```
(defun parse (string)
  (mapcar (lambda (line)
            (let* ((k_v (split-string line "="))
                   (key (intern (first k_v))) ; change here
               (val (second k_v)))
              (list key val)))
          (split-string string "\n" t)))
```

`(intern "foo")` returns the *interned* symbol `foo`, which will be added to your alist, allowing `(assq 'foo alist)` to work just fine.

(Tested on my Emacs 24.2.1 on Win7.)

Comment: Thanks! I had just reached the point of discovering that `(make-symbol "foo")` was neither `equal` nor `eq` to `'foo`, and feeling even more confused. :-)